# How to change django admin "view site" link to custom absolute url

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rest, django-admin

I have REST API built on Django and JS application. Both are on different domains. How to change django admin "VIEW SITE" link in such way so it will open JS application? I've tried to pass absolute link (https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_url), but looks like it does not work - only relative paths allowed

Answer (score 22):

I prefer resetting `admin.site.site_url` in `urls.py`, along with other site changes (instead of doing this in an `admin.py` file, cause a project can have serveral admin.py)

```
# urls.py
admin.site.site_url = ''  # Removes the 'View Site' link
admin.site.site_header = 'My Site'
```

Comment: This is pretty slick, and I use it to customize additional admin interface components: `admin.site.site_title = "Company Title"`, `admin.site.index_title = "Administration Portal"`, etc...

Comment: If you want to remove the 'View Site' link, I would advise using  `admin.site.site_url = ""` instead of setting the variable to `None` as it is intended to be assigned a string value, which can mess up with `mypy` if you're using it

Comment: My project is running behind a reverse proxy so I updated project/urls.py with the following line:
```admin.site.site_url = f'/{settings.URL_PREFIX}'``` and ```URL_PREFIX='project-name'``` is defined in settings.py .

Answer (score 16):

In Django 1.11.5, it seems that :
`from django.contrib import admin` and
`admin.site.site_url = 'https:....'` in the **admin.py** file is enough

Comment: Note that setting `admin.site.site_url` to `None` removes the link altogether - which may be useful in certain occasions.

Comment: Here's what the latest [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_url) have to say about it.

Answer (score 11):

By default , "VIEW SITE" points to '/' i.e localhost:8000 (Default settings assumed).

To change it , use (in admin.py):

```
admin.site.site_url = "/mySite"
```

Tested on Django 2.1

Comment: where do you add this setting?

Comment: @jewles...in admin.py

Answer (score 5):

There are two solutions I can come up with.

Firstly, you could use custom template `admin/base.html`. But, reading through the default template, you would have to copy-paste a lot of code just to change a link, which seems like an overkill.

Another solution involves [overriding `AdminSite`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class). `AdminSite` has a property called `site_url`, and it seems like changing it would do the job. So, in essense, you can do something like this:

**your_app/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from .models import MyModel

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_url = 'https://yourdomain.com'

admin_site = MyAdminSite(name='myadmin')
```

**your_project/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp.admin import admin_site

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^myadmin/', admin_site.urls),
]
```

And you should register all your models with your custom admin, not Django's default:

```
from your_app.admin import admin_site
admin_site.register(MyModel)
```

Answer (score 4):

Default link to viewsite is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

We can change it to custom url through register it in **admin.py**

```
admin.site.site_url = "/mySite"
```

Example : admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from auth_app.models import profile
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(profile)
#register link
admin.site.site_url = "/mySite"
```

Answer (score 1):

In admin.py, mention your custom path like following

```
admin.site.site_url = "/<Your Path>"
```

If your custom url is like "https://example.com/dashboard", You have to put below line in your admin.py

```
admin.site.site_url = "/dashboard"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change **"VIEW SITE" link** by changing **"admin.site.site_url"** which is **"/"** by default:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

print(admin.site.site_url) # /

admin.site.site_url = "/example"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep in mind that if you are setting the reference (in either a template or in the .py file) it is going to build the url assuming that you gave it a relative component (`/mything` becomes `www.mysite.com/mything`).  If you want to go to a completely different url you must include the "https://" and give the full url.

Answer (score 1):

`reverse` not work for urls route, you can config it like this:

```
from django.urls import include, path, reverse_lazy

admin.site.site_header = "MyAdmin"
admin.site.site_title = "MyAdmin"
admin.site.index_title = "MyAdmin Panel"
admin.site.site_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard:home')
```